# python prints folders and sub folders when only folders needed in python

Tags: python, directory, python-os

I am making a program that prints all the folders over 90 days in python.
Here is my code:

```
import os
from datetime import date
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog


old_dirs = []
today = date.today()

home1 = os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop")
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(initialdir=desktop, title="Select folder to 
scan from: ")
path = path.encode('utf-8')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in dirs:
        filedate = date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, name)))
        if (today - filedate).days > 90:
            print name
            old_dirs.append(name)
```

The problem is that this prints all folders, but it also prints the sub folders of the folders, which I don't need. How can I change the code so that it only prints the folders?

Answer (score 2):

Just break after printing the dirs:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in dirs:
        filedate = date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, name)))
        if (today - filedate).days > 90:
            print name
            old_dirs.append(name)
    break
```

Or look into using `os.listdir()`, that doesn't recurse into the subdirectories (but you'll have to check for non-directories in the result).

Answer (score 1):

```
(root, dirs, files) = next(os.walk(path))
for name in dirs:
```

or alternatively use `os.listdir`

Comment: Right, using `next` instead of indexing is in order here.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; [...]

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in dirs:
        filedate = date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, name)))
        if (today - filedate).days > 90:
            print name
            old_dirs.append(name)
    del dirs[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

An example using `os.listdir`:

```
root = os.getcwd()

for name in os.listdir(path):
    full_path = os.path.join(root, name)

    if os.path.isdir(full_path):
        filedate = date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(full_path))

        if (today - filedate).days > 90:
            old_dirs.append(name)
```

`os.path.isdir` will return true if a file is a directory only.